# How can I call a function inside a procedure in plsql

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsqldeveloper

I want to call a function inside a procedure and get it's value so I can use within the procedure but I have no idea how to do that ?? 
Any ideas ??
My function is the following one , this function returns a collection of employees' ids whose salary out of the max or min salary  , I want to use this value in a procedure to update the salaries of those employees to the minimum salary ??

Comment: Try to solve this with an UPDATE rather than a mishmash of stored procedures. When you say "this function returns a collection of employee's ids" that IS a set, which is best obtained by an SELECT statement.

Answer (score 6):

```
create or replace procedure P
    a_variable_name number;
begin
    a_variable := a_function('a parameter');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code that will help you calling a function from a procedure.

```
    create or replace FUNCTION ADD_TEN(P_IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
    L_RESULT VARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN
    L_RESULT:=P_IN+10;
    RETURN L_RESULT;
    END;



    create or replace PROCEDURE CALL_FUNCTON(P_IN VARCHAR2)
        AS
        L_FINAL_RESULT VARCHAR2(4000);
        BEGIN
        L_FINAL_RESULT:=ADD_TEN(P_IN);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_FINAL_RESULT);
        -- USE L_FINAL_RESULT IN YOUR BUSINESS LOGIC
        END;

EXECUTE CALL_FUNCTON(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare

procedure my_proc;
```

function my_func return number is

```
begin

my_proc;

return 3;

end my_func;
```

procedure my_proc is

```
begin

dbms_output.put_line('22');

end my_proc;

begin

dbms_output.put_line(my_func);

end;
```